# How to toggle a command with a keypress in Arch Linux using i3

Tags: bash, sh, key-bindings, archlinux

I find the mouse pad on my laptop annoying because I often brush it with my arm when I am typing so I figured I would make a toggle to turn it off and back on again when I want to use the mouse. For some reason synaptics doesn't pick up my mouse pad so I'm resorting to using `xinput disable 11` with 11 being the ID of my mouse pad. I'm trying to use bindsym in the i3 config to make "m" toggle the mouse pad. I've made an sh script to disable the mousepad but it doesn't seem to turn back on when I press "m" again. I figured I would make a system variable to determine whether the mousepad is on or not but the sh script doesn't seem to see it properly. This is my script at the moment called "trackpad" in /bin:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]
then
    xinput enable 11 && export TRACKPAD=0
else
    xinput disable 11 && export TRACKPAD=1
fi
```

Then in my i3 config file I have:

```
bindsym $mod+m exec trackpad $TRACKPAD
```

I'm not sure if this is even the best method to do this so any alternative suggestions would be great. Otherwise, how can I fix this? I'm fairly new to Linux.

Comment: Can you check with `xinput` if the device is enabled currently or not? That would likely be the simplest solution. `export` only applies to the current process and any children processes, it doesn't escape those boundaries so you can't use it like this. It would need to be an `i3` variable you used to track this for it to work as an argument.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that shows if a device is enabled/disabled with xinput... How do make and use an i3 variable in this case?

Comment: I don't know. I don't even know if you can. I don't use `i3`. My point was that you need to keep the state outside/above the script (and the scripts environment) if you want a toggle like this to work. If you can trigger a change in the `i3` binding you could do it that way too. Each run sets the binding to the opposite argument value (or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xinput` offers the argument `list-props` for listing all properties of a device. At least with my touchpad, executing `xinput enable` and `xinput disable` toggles the property `Device Enabled` (0/1). Greping the status of this property makes you able to test if the device is currently enabled.

A quick-and-dirty approach to use this for your problem *could* be the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
if xinput list-props 11 | grep -qE "Device Enabled.*1$"
then 
    xinput disable 11
else 
    xinput enable 11
fi
```

or as a simple one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput list-props 11 | grep -qE "Device Enabled.*1$" && xinput disable 11 || xinput enable 11
```

As you can see those scripts don't need an argument to be passed. Simple execution toggles the device-state.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! :)